# Magento 2 - How to export all messages for translation

Tags: magento2, translate, error-message

In magento 2, I need to export in file all alert and error messages in order to translate them.

I already try this :

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases app/code/ -o translate.csv
```

But this not exactly what I want because every text are exported, I just want alert or error messages.

Do you know a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Magento all strings that are to be translated are treated by the system in the same way, regardless if that is used as an error message or as a success message. So you have to filter your translate.csv manually.
Anyway, the best approach is to translate them all.